# Python: How to extract numbers and certain upercase letters after a keyword

Tags: python, pandas, string

I'm trying to extract the digits after the word 'Amount' and the currency code after the digits into two separate columns using Python. Any help would be appreciated.

Successful refund. IBE payment ID 79104467 | Transaction-ref: 73462794 | Amount: 50.00 EUR

Successful refund by Hyperwallet. Transaction-ref: 48886217 | Amount: 214.64 USD | Hyperwallet payout id: 581082-2

Comment: can you post this as a reproducible df? It makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To construct a DataFrame from the given string try:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

s = """\
Successful refund. IBE payment ID 79104467 | Transaction-ref: 73462794 | Amount: 50.00 EUR
Successful refund by Hyperwallet. Transaction-ref: 48886217 | Amount: 214.64 USD | Hyperwallet payout id: 581082-2"""

df = pd.DataFrame(
    re.findall(r"Amount:\s*([\d.]+)\s*([^\s]+)", s),
    columns=["Amount", "Currency"],
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Amount Currency
0   50.00      EUR
1  214.64      USD
```

Comment: I think this did it for me. Thanks soo much for this. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use regex for that

```py
import re
def listAmounts(s):
    return [a for a,b in re.findall('(\d+(\.\d+)?\s[A-Z]+)', s)]
```

(Returns any strings made of some digits, and an optional dot with some more digits, and a space and some uppercase letters. You can of course use some variant, allowing more spaces or no space before currency, or fixing the number of digits after dot, or allowing sign, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but should work

```
to_filter = 'Successful refund. IBE payment ID 79104467 | Transaction-ref: 73462794 | Amount: 50.00 EUR'
to_filter = to_filter.split(' ')
amount = [float(to_filter[to_filter.index('Amount:') + 1]), to_filter[to_filter.index('Amount:') + 2]]
print(amount)
```